# Subtly for where the gradient vector "lives"

Tags: multivariable-calculus

True or False: The vector $\nabla f(a,b)$ is a vector in space orthogonal to the surface $z=f(x,y)$ at the point $(a,b)$.

It turns out this is false. The answer says:

"This gradient vector is a vector in the plane, not in space!" An explanation would be great!

Comment: It has only two partial derivatives. Just take $f(x,y) = xy$ and try to compute it.

Comment: The surface $z=f(x,y)$ is in $\Bbb R^3$.  But the gradient only has two components $(\partial_x f, \partial_y f)$.  So the gradient is in $\Bbb R^2$.  Thus the gradient and the surface exist in different spaces.

Comment: Isn't the vector in 3d space though? Like a plane in 3d space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are talking about a function $f:{\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}$ here. Such a function has level sets
$$\gamma_C:=\bigl\{(x,y)\>\bigm|\>f(x,y)=C\bigr\}\qquad(-\infty<C<\infty)\ ,$$
which "generically" are smooth curves.

Take a point $(a,b)$ in the domain of $f$, and assume $f(a,b)=c$. Then $(a,b)\in\gamma_c$. The vector $\nabla f(a,b):=\bigl({\partial f\over\partial x}, {\partial f\over\partial y}\bigr)_{(a,b)}$ is a vector attached at $(a,b)$, and is lying in the $(x,y)$-plane. If this vector is $\ne(0,0)$ then $\gamma_c$ is indeed a smooth curve in the neighborhood of $(a,b)$, and $\nabla f(a,b)$ is orthogonal to (the tangent of) $\gamma_c$ at $(a,b)$.